# DoctrineExtension: Sluggable on Mongodb's Embedded Document

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, slug

I'm following the [doctrine extension installation guide](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/symfony2.md) to set up slugs in mongodb documents. I'm able to do that without any problem. However, it does NOT seem to work on embedded documents. It simply does not populate the specified slug field. No error is thrown.

I'm just curious has anybody been able to generate slugs on mongodb's embedded document? If so, is there any additional settings that I need to specify? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it wasn't the problem with DoctrineExtension. I was trying to persist the embedded document when I should be persisting the parent document. Therefore, the embedded document was never saved.